# i tried to upload cloud function but always getting HTTP Error: 400,

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

im trying to upload my cloud function using teriminal it works when i only upload newsubscribenotification function but always failed when i try to upload function susbcriber, can anyone give me advice, im new in firebase enviroment and node js, thank you so much

this is my code

```
     const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore.document('Classroom/{classId}/Homework/{HomeId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        let newValue = snap.data().topic;
        let question = snap.data().question;
        let title = snap.data().title;
        console.log(newValue);
        const userId = context.params.classId;
        const homeId = context.params.HomeId;
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(homeId);
        pushMessage(newValue,question,title);
        return true;
    });
    exports.subscriber = functions.firestore.document('Classroom/{classId1}/Homework/StudentWork/{HomeId1}')
    .onCreate((snap1, contex1t) => {
        let newValue1 = snap1.data().topic;
        let question1 = snap1.data().answer;
        let title1 = snap.data().path;
        const userId = context1.params.classId1;
        const homeId = context1.params.HomeId1;
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(homeId);
        pushMessage(newValue1,question1,title1);
    });
function pushMessage(newValue,question,title) {
    var payload = {
      notification: {
        title:question,
        body:title
      }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(newValue, payload);
}
```

i have tried to read another question but it dosent work thank you

this is my error code

```
!  functions: failed to create function subscriber
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
+  functions[newSubscriberNotification(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        subscriber
```

Comment: You are having problems with this function exports.subscriber

Comment: can you gve me spesific path for the error?

Comment: Sorry, the error log just says that the error is inside that specific function, can you log a little more detail ?

Comment: do you mean log in the firebase dashboard or my terminal, ibecause in the terminal the error only http error 400, thank you